# Extjs Context Menu with Tree Panel

Tags: extjs, coolite

I have a tree panel and I want to show context menu to each tree node when right click to be able to delete it

please help me as soon as you can

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer in the following link :

http://www.coolite.com/forums/Topic6418-16-1.aspx#bm8010

Thanks